# Goodness of fit - Large deviation

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value

The Pearson test (chi test) provide a mean to evaluate whether a given sample (empirical distribution) match the theoretical one. The test compute the p-value, which is the probability for seen the given sample conditioned the true distribution is the theoretical one.

The p-value is compared to a threshold alpha which is usually not too small..

The question is as follow:
Suppose I want to use very small alpha (1e-10), how should I change the test?

I was thinking that like in the analysis of large deviation, I should find a representive bad sample and calculate its probability but I suspect that I might missing something..

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't change the test at all, but you should be cautious about using the chi-squared approximation until you have confirmed it is accurate *in your circumstance* that far out in the tail.

Comment: I am not sure about this. My issue is NOT with the calculation of the chi square but with the converges of the statistics to the chi-distribution in this regime.

Comment: When the bins are fixed, the convergence will occur--that is theoretically established.  The convergence, of course, is to the chi *squared* distribution, not the *chi* distribution.

Comment: 1. I ment the chi-square distribution - of course

Comment: 2. Thoretically, it will converge when I regard alpha as constant but what if it is also depends on n?

Comment: Then it depends on how $\alpha$ varies with $n.$  It would be an extremely unusual statistical setting in which that occurred, though.

Comment: Using sanov's theorem, the KL distance between the a-priori distribution and the empirical distribution should proivde an exponential rate for the probability of the event, right?

Comment: I doubt that, because you are probing extreme tail probabilities.  The KL distance doesn't tell you much about that.